# Flutter iOS Notification Image Issue

Tags: ios, flutter, notifications

I have installed extension from following link for receive image in push notification for IOS

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration/#step-1---add-a-notification-service-extension

Error:

Cycle inside Runner; building could produce unreliable results.
Cycle details:
→ Target 'Runner': ExtractAppIntentsMetadata
○ Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/aarav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gahtiqfbuzgkxpgmjpuomdwfvlxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ImageNotification.appex' to '/Users/aarav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gahtiqfbuzgkxpgmjpuomdwfvlxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/PlugIns/ImageNotification.appex'
○ That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “Thin Binary”
○ Target 'Runner' has process command with output '/Users/aarav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gahtiqfbuzgkxpgmjpuomdwfvlxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Info.plist'
○ Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/aarav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gahtiqfbuzgkxpgmjpuomdwfvlxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ImageNotification.appex' to '/Users/aarav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gahtiqfbuzgkxpgmjpuomdwfvlxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/PlugIns/ImageNotification.appex'

Raw dependency cycle trace:

target:  ->

node:  ->

command:  ->

node: /Users/aarav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gahtiqfbuzgkxpgmjpuomdwfvlxv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ExtractedAppShortcutsMetadata.stringsdata ->

command: P0:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:ExtractAppIntentsMetadata ->

node:  ->

command: P0:::Gate target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49--fused-phase7-copy-files ->

node: <Copy /Users/aarav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gahtiqfbuzgkxpgmjpuomdwfvlxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/PlugIns/ImageNotification.appex> ->

CYCLE POINT ->

command: P0:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:Copy /Users/aarav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gahtiqfbuzgkxpgmjpuomdwfvlxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/PlugIns/ImageNotification.appex /Users/aarav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gahtiqfbuzgkxpgmjpuomdwfvlxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ImageNotification.appex ->

node:  ->

command: P0:::Gate target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49--fused-phase6--cp--embed-pods-frameworks ->

node: /Users/aarav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gahtiqfbuzgkxpgmjpuomdwfvlxv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/InputFileList-8D1EE483BF264E895E1F2997-Pods-Runner-frameworks-Debug-input-files-aa1984aa42c0d97d5830653bd55e96fd-resolved.xcfilelist ->

command: P2:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/aarav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gahtiqfbuzgkxpgmjpuomdwfvlxv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/InputFileList-8D1EE483BF264E895E1F2997-Pods-Runner-frameworks-Debug-input-files-aa1984aa42c0d97d5830653bd55e96fd-resolved.xcfilelist ->

node:  ->

command: P0:::Gate target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49--fused-phase5--firebase-crashlytics--crashlytics-upload-symbols ->

node: /Users/aarav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gahtiqfbuzgkxpgmjpuomdwfvlxv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-4532A44EBDD4D84C9CCF9672.sh ->

command: P2:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/aarav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gahtiqfbuzgkxpgmjpuomdwfvlxv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-4532A44EBDD4D84C9CCF9672.sh ->

node:  ->

command: P0:::Gate target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49--fused-phase4-thin-binary ->

node:  ->

command: P2:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:PhaseScriptExecution Thin Binary /Users/aarav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gahtiqfbuzgkxpgmjpuomdwfvlxv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-3B06AD1E1E4923F5004D2608.sh ->

node: /Users/aarav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gahtiqfbuzgkxpgmjpuomdwfvlxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Info.plist/ ->

directoryTreeSignature: � ->

directoryContents: /Users/aarav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gahtiqfbuzgkxpgmjpuomdwfvlxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Info.plist ->

node: /Users/aarav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gahtiqfbuzgkxpgmjpuomdwfvlxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Info.plist ->

command: P0:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:ProcessInfoPlistFile /Users/aarav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gahtiqfbuzgkxpgmjpuomdwfvlxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Info.plist /Users/aarav/Documents/Client/Astroljal/FlutterProject/NRIHelpLine/ios/Runner/Info.plist ->

node: /Users/aarav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gahtiqfbuzgkxpgmjpuomdwfvlxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/PlugIns/ImageNotification.appex ->

command: P0:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:Copy /Users/aarav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gahtiqfbuzgkxpgmjpuomdwfvlxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/PlugIns/ImageNotification.appex /Users/aarav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gahtiqfbuzgkxpgmjpuomdwfvlxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ImageNotification.appex

I have also tried to

- uninstall pod and reinstall the pods
- ⁠clean the ios project and retry

but still same issue facing.